# Splunk MongoDB addon: do we need root priviledge to monitoring MongoDB data?

Tags: mongodb, splunk

Experts：

If I am going to monitor following data /1/, we are using Splunk MongoDB addon, do we need root privilege to get the moniotoring data?

/1/

```
Number of commands
Number of asserts users
Number of asserts messages
Number of available connections
Number of current connections
Connection Growth
Number of network bytes in
Number of network bytes out
Number of network requests
Mapped memory size 
Virtual memory size 
Resident memory size 
Replica Set availability   
Member status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the MongoDB Monitoring app (https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/2957/), the docs listed at https://github.com/jruaux/mongodb-monitoring say it does not require root, but you may need to enable admin privileges.

You may need to use syslog to send data out, or modify the permissions on mongod.log to allow Splunk to read it